# How to use existing Video Intercom device with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B?

Tags: pi-3

I have [image: Honeywell video intercom] device which doesn't have video recording support.
Currently when someone rings my door bell I could see that person on display screen attached inside my home. But I want to know "missed door bells"
I want to know who came and rang my door bell when I was not at home.

All I want to do is to take a snap or record short video/gif of that person who ring my door bell.
Is it possible to use existing video stream which intercom is sending to display to record the video or take picture ?

Comment: It is as easy as, you connect your Pi with the intercom and run a video capturing software every time the bell rings.

Comment: Seriously. You have a clear target but the description of your devices and skills is very vague. There might or might not be a way to connect your Pi to the intercom. But that will require propper technical documentation of your intercom to judge that. Instead you can work around the heavy part and install a "bell detector" that triggers the pi camera that is attached right before the mointor.

Comment: Thanks. I've added link to image for description of my intercom device. It has a/v output, can I use it ? and if yes, how ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need an USB Video Grabber like this one (https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0013BXFLG). This is no recommendation for a particular device but a hint on what kind of device you need! With that you will get a `/dev/video*` device where you can grab frames using v4l2 library in python, C or any other language with a binding.

Additionally you will need a cable with a 3 or 4 pole Jack on one side and RCA on the other side. (The pinout may vary so not all cable will work. But you can test it with TV first.)